# 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized error SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, state

Any idea why this will give 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized error

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var activities : [ActivityModel]
   @State private var currentAcitivity : ActivityModel
   init() {
      let tmpActivities : [ActivityModel] = [ActivityModel(name: "@Home", notes: "At Home", schedule: nil)
      ,ActivityModel(name: "@Work", notes: "At Work", schedule: nil)]

      _activities = State<[ActivityModel]>(wrappedValue:  tmpActivities)
      _currentAcitivity = State<ActivityModel>(wrappedValue: tmpActivities[0])
      
   }
```

Comment: This does not. I assume the reason is in other code. Would you show more?

Comment: @Asperi, thanks for the hint, ActivityModel was not observable.

Answer (score 3):

Because `@State` is not meant to inherit from higher `Views`. ["You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state). Use an alternative such as [`@Binding` which can receive from an `@State`from a parent `View`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) or an [`@EnvironmentObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) which receives from an `@ObservedObject`

```
import SwiftUI

struct StateDemo: View {
    @Binding var array: [String]
    
    init(higherViewArray: Binding<[String]>){
        self._array = higherViewArray
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("list")
            ForEach(array, id: \.self){ txt in
                Text(txt)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StateDemo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StateDemo(higherViewArray: .constant( ["0", "1", "2"]))
    }
}
```